# I have to parse and use the data I get from the API using retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I need to be able to use it like progress `["5db0291a02306577129dc153"]["5db028ab02306577129dc0c6"]`.progress. How do I store it in models? What datatype to use and how to retrieve?

Here is the data that I get:

```
"progress": {
            "5db0291a02306577129dc153": {
                "name": "Default Course - Cyber Security Essentials",
                "type": "course",
                "5db028ab02306577129dc0c6": {
                    "name": "Module 1",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "5db028ab02306577129dc0c7": {
                    "name": "Module 2",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "5db028ab02306577129dc0c8": {
                    "name": "Module 3",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "5db028ab02306577129dc0c9": {
                    "name": "Module 4",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "5db028ab02306577129dc0ca": {
                    "name": "Module 5",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 0
                },
                "5db028ab02306577139dc0c1": {
                    "name": "Module 6",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "5db028ab02306577139dc0cc": {
                    "name": "Module 7",
                    "type": "module",
                    "progress": 100
                },
                "progress": 85.71428571428571
            },
            "progress": 85.71428571428571
        }
```

Comment: post complete response here please

Comment: he's just missing the outer curly braces {"progress": {...}}

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using this website "https://www.json2kotlin.com/" to generate the data classes needed as Models, then i would suggest making them all implement the Serializable interface, for the return type of the network call set it as the main Model class and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin in android studio name `DTO Generator` you can find this plugin by going to File->Settings->Plugins it will be on the Featured list, if you are unable to find it you can search it in the same window

after installing just create a new class which you want to use as Model, name it something similar - `progressModel.class` or something which suits you

press `alt+Insert` which will open `Generate` windows, you will see a new option `DTO from JSON` paste you JSON output in the windows and configure settings 
I use `Single File with inner class` `Gson` `Make Fields Private` and `Provide Getter`
then simply click generate and it will generate a POJO Model class for you.

Hope this will help!

Comment: I can't possibly create POJO classes for all the "Keys".

Comment: keys should be same, in your case keys are different in every step, so this will be not easy to find any solution for that, what will be the best option is to change the JSON response

Comment: Can't do that. API can't be changed for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website which will convert your json to its corresponding model/beans.

Your models should look somewhat like these https://pastebin.com/5EWpTmxC

You can use the below code snippet to map the response json to your model class.

```
public static Object mapBean(String response, Class cls) {
        response = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(response);
        Gson _gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        Object obj;
        try {
            obj = _gson.fromJson(response, cls);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            obj = null;
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: The names of the keys will change based on the response, I can't possibly create POJOs for every key (like 5db028ab02306577129dc0c8, 5db028ab02306577139dc0c1) here. There could be thousands of them.

Comment: The json you provided contains a nesting, an outer key with inner keys, can you explain how this json response values relate to the front end?

Comment: It is possible to get all the keys in the nested json and then traverse the json using the keys to get the data you need accordingly.

Comment: What I basically need is to get the progress. I have courseID and moduleID saved locally and I need to use that to get the corresponding progress like progress["courseid"]["moduleid"].progress

Comment: @ZubairZahoor You have mentioned that the api cannot be changed correct?. I tested out your json https://jsfiddle.net/5cba7zg3/, if you already have the course id and module id saved with you and only need to access those it can be done, refer the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I used JsonElement provided by the Gson Library as datatype for the data. Then I did
    `JsonObject progress=jsonelement.getAsJsonObject;
int moduleprogress= progress.getASJsonObject(courseid).getAsJsonObject(moduleid).get("progress").getAsInt();`